# Gitlab CI/CD using Kubernetes agent and the private container registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I will preface this by saying that I know very little about how to manage Kuberentes clusters, so I am probably doing something dumb. Here goes:

I have created a Kubernetes cluster using GCP's Autopilot mode, and I (think I) registered the cluster to my Gitlab repository using the "Infrastructure->Kubernetes Clusters" menu (It shows as online).

Using Gitlab's CI/CD, I have a `build` stage which pushes an image to the repo's container registry (I see the the image is indeed there).

I then have a `deploy` stage with the following script: (censored some data for privacy)

```sh
kubectl config use-context <my_username>/<my_reponame>:<my_reponame>
kubectl delete secret regcred --ignore-not-found
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server="$CI_REGISTRY" --docker-username="$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --docker-password="$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
kubectl delete pod <my_reponame> --ignore-not-found
kubectl apply -f kube.yaml
```

My `kube.yaml` contains the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: <my_reponame>
spec:
  containers:
    - name: <my_reponame>
      image: registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
```

I also have a `.gitlab/agents/<my_reponame>/config.yaml` file with the following:

```yaml
ci_access:
  projects:
    - id: <my_username>/<my_reponame>
```

This is the output of the build stage:

```sh
Running with gitlab-runner 14.8.0~beta.44.g57df0d52 (57df0d52)
  on blue-2.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default XxUrkriX
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:12
Using Docker executor with image bitnami/kubectl:latest ...
Pulling docker image bitnami/kubectl:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:208d070e071a0165e48ad7bf20b30c054328bcaaad76b0c53a9270a5e8627480 for bitnami/kubectl:latest with digest bitnami/kubectl@sha256:51eb9cb7d811e74bba30f97700cb433424d4025aabe70e8ff80e1289a964ab9c ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-xxurkrix-project-32365648-concurrent-0 via runner-xxurkrix-shared-1646113353-c926e727...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/<my_username>/<my_reponame>/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 23743f89 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:13
Using docker image sha256:208d070e071a0165e48ad7bf20b30c054328bcaaad76b0c53a9270a5e8627480 for bitnami/kubectl:latest with digest bitnami/kubectl@sha256:51eb9cb7d811e74bba30f97700cb433424d4025aabe70e8ff80e1289a964ab9c ...
$ kubectl config use-context <my_username>/<my_reponame>:<my_reponame>
Switched to context "<my_username>/<my_reponame>:<my_reponame>".
$ kubectl delete secret regcred --ignore-not-found
secret "regcred" deleted
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server="$CI_REGISTRY" --docker-username="$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --docker-password="$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
secret/regcred created
$ kubectl delete pod <my_reponame> --ignore-not-found
$ kubectl apply -f kube.yaml
Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Pod default/<my_reponame>, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults.
pod/<my_reponame> created
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

However, the deploy to the cluster did not actually work.
Here is some data from running in the gcloud shell

```sh
<my_username>@cloudshell:~ (<my_reponame>-342620)$ kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
<my_reponame>                  0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          13h
<my_reponame>-69775f4b-cft8w   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          13h
```

```sh
kubectl get pod <my_reponame> -o yaml`

Name:         <my_reponame>
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gk3-<my_reponame>-nap-73l1ao51-a8e3ee2d-wjd8/10.132.0.5
Start Time:   Tue, 01 Mar 2022 19:11:18 +0000
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  autopilot.gke.io/resource-adjustment:
                {"input":{"containers":[{"name":"<my_reponame>"}]},"output":{"containers":[{"limits":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"requ...
              seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.34.0.77
IPs:
  IP:  10.34.0.77
Containers:
  <my_reponame>:
    Container ID:
    Image:          registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             2Gi
    Environment:          <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-96wsd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-96wsd:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From                                   Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----                                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled  17s               gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/<my_reponame> to gk3-<my_reponame>-nap-73l1ao51-a8e3ee2d-wjd8
  Warning  Failed     14s               kubelet                                Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
  Normal   BackOff    14s               kubelet                                Back-off pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest"
  Warning  Failed     14s               kubelet                                Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    2s (x2 over 16s)  kubelet                                Pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest"
  Warning  Failed     1s (x2 over 14s)  kubelet                                Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     1s                kubelet                                Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": failed to resolve reference "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

`kubectl get pod <my_reponame> -o yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    autopilot.gke.io/resource-adjustment: '{"input":{"containers":[{"name":"<my_reponame>"}]},"output":{"containers":[{"limits":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"500m","ephemeral-storage":"1Gi","memory":"2Gi"},"name":"<my_reponame>"}]},"modified":true}'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"<my_reponame>","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest","name":"<my_reponame>"}],"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"regcred"}]}}
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-01T19:11:18Z"
  name: <my_reponame>
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1299911"
  uid: d8a636ee-1dfc-40e9-9ba4-26b5674d3259
spec:
  containers:
  - image: registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: <my_reponame>
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
        memory: 2Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
        memory: 2Gi
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - NET_RAW
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-96wsd
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
  nodeName: gk3-<my_reponame>-nap-73l1ao51-a8e3ee2d-wjd8
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-96wsd
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-01T19:11:18Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-01T19:11:18Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [<my_reponame>]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-01T19:11:18Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [<my_reponame>]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-01T19:11:18Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - image: registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: <my_reponame>
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    started: false
    state:
      waiting:
        message: 'rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image
          "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": failed to resolve reference
          "registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_reponame>:latest": failed to authorize: failed
          to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized'
        reason: ErrImagePull
  hostIP: 10.132.0.5
  phase: Pending
  podIP: 10.34.0.77
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.34.0.77
  qosClass: Guaranteed
  startTime: "2022-03-01T19:11:18Z"
```

It looks like from the last commands log that it was not able to pull from the container registry - I assume I passed the credentials wrong, but I could not find any example or documentation on how to achieve this.

I'm of course willing to give any info if necessary.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you check logs for this pod or `kubectl describe` command on this pod and attach info to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://chris-vermeulen.com/using-gitlab-registry-with-kubernetes/, your cluster cannot pull from the registry because it has no access.